# Why additional location in nginx conf returns 404 code?

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I have this configuration for my virtual host:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /var/www/home;
    access_log /var/www/home/access.log;
    error_log /var/www/home/error.log;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name home;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args; #if doesn't exist, send it to index.php
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php-fpm.sock;

        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "error_log=/var/www/home/php_errors.log";
    }

    location ~* /Admin {
        allow 127.0.0.1;
        deny all;
    }
}
```

When I am trying to access page /Admin nginx returns 404 code with successful html content generated by php. When location with /Admin removed, everything goes well.

How to get what is the problem with additional location ?

Answer (score 1):

You should read [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) to understand the precedence order of the various kinds of location block.

So, you could place your regex location above the `location ~ \.php$` block to allow it to take precedence, or change it to:

```
location ^~ /Admin { ... }
```

which is a prefix location that takes precedence over any regex location (in which case its order within the file becomes irrelevant).

The second problem is the purpose of the `allow 127.0.0.1` statement. Are you are expecting to execute `.php` files with an `/Admin` prefix from a client at 127.0.0.1?

Your admin location block contains no code to execute `.php` files. If the intention is to execute `.php` files with an `/Admin` prefix, you could try:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php-fpm.sock;

    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "error_log=/var/www/home/php_errors.log";
}

location ^~ /Admin {
    allow 127.0.0.1;
    deny all;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php-fpm.sock;

        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

You may want to use the `include` directive to move common statements into a separate file.

See [how `nginx` processes a request](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html).